# Node not able to serve large files?

Tags: node.js, file, hapi.js, static-files

I am using Node with hapi.

For file serving, it works well up to 1.8 GB files. When I tried to serve a file of 2.4 GB, it seems that something is going wrong and an empty directory got downloaded. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `res.pipe` to send the file in chunks. This is some sample code that I use for streaming large file. But it is not the complete code. It should be enough to lead you in the right direction.

```js
if (req.headers.range) {
  contentType = mime.lookup(filePath);
  var range = req.headers.range;
  var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
  var partialstart = parts[0] || "0";
  var partialend = parts[1];

  var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
  var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : fileSize - 1;
  var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
  var file = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {
    start: start,
    end: end
  });
  res.writeHead(206, {
    'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + fileSize,
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Content-Length': chunksize,
    'Content-Type': contentType
  });
  file.pipe(res);
  return;
}
```